# Ruby 1.9 performance issue with Array#flatten

Tags: ruby

I have two questions regarding the performance of the Array#flatten method.

Below is a simple test comparing the flatten method to a home-made naive implementation with Enumerable#inject.

a) How can my inject code perform significantly better than the native flatten implementation - and I am using the flatten(1) version

b) What is the spike in time observed every 10 or so lines in the test - could this be a garbage collecting effect?

```
array = (1..3).collect {(1..100).to_a}
30.times {100.times {array.flatten(1)}}
30.times {100.times {array.inject([]) {|a, e| a += e}}}
```

with a formatted tracking code

```
30.times {now = Time.now; 100.times {array.flatten(1)};                 p "#{(1000 * (Time.now - now)).to_i.to_s.rjust(4)}ms"}
30.times {now = Time.now; 100.times {array.inject([]) {|a, e| a += e}}; p "#{(1000 * (Time.now - now)).to_i.to_s.rjust(4)}ms"}
```

I've tried this in plain irb and also a Rails script/console environment with the same results.  The inject version outperforms significantly the Array#flatten method.

Comment: Perhaps the native implementation is thread-safe?

Comment: @yock: What is thread unsafe about the inject version? @Jason: One difference I can see is that your version simply assumes every element is an array, while flatten has to check (so e.g. `[1, [2], 3]` works with `flatten`, but will fail with your `inject` version).

Comment: Btw: Doing `a += e` in the block is completely equivalent to just doing `a + e` without reassigning `a` (given that `a` goes out of scope right away anyway).

Comment: I can see same kind of performance differencies on 1.8.7. Have you tried `array.inject(:+)`? It seems to be even faster while producing same results. http://pastebin.com/bdbCvyqF

Comment: Thank you both sepp2k and Heikki for the great comments.  inject(:+) is definitely the right answer for me as I will be working with arrays with known content.  The more flexible nature of flatten could indeed be a good explanation.